# web3 installer not installing dist folder?

Tags: web3js

I've tried to install web3 with node.js by doing `npm install web3 --save`, but when I check the `node_modules` folder,  there's no `dist` folder and its `web3.min.js` file anywhere. Any ideas on how or why? Thanks

Comment: Having the same problem too. Cant find the `dist` folder.